# How do I log using gunicorn and multiprocessing?

Tags: python, logging, flask, gunicorn

How do I use python logging to log my application code (not access logs) in a multiprocessing gunicorn (and Flask) application?

Do I need centralized logging solution or I could somehow use a file? Is it safe to just point each process to the same file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use multiprocessing logger:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#logging

Or if you want you can write the logs to a different file in each process by concating the pid to the file name

Comment: Since gunicorn creates the process, is calling multiprocessing.get_logger() enough?

Comment: Yes, multiprocessing.get_logger() is simply a process-safe logger